# Show image on desktop

Tags: photos

I want to show a photo on my desktop.

I don't want it to be my desktop background, or my screen saver, but I'd just like it be on the desktop so I can look at it, bigger than a thumbnail (maybe a couple of inches by a couple of inches).

What's the best way to do this? I can see how to resize every thumbnail, but that's not what I want.

I'd rather not run an app to do this - is there any way I can do this within OSX?

Comment: To clarify, you want an image to be on your desktop, but not have the image be your desktop background? Also, would you want to open a Preview window with the image?

Comment: Most people edit that photo on to the background in the size you want. Why the requirements on no app? Generally people will always say a way to do it natively if it’s possible, so removing that restriction generally gets you more options.

Comment: @Jake3231 yes, exactly, thanks! And no, I don't mind about opening a Preview window.

Comment: @bmike ah ok, thanks! Didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geektool does exactly that

I think this is the correct download url https://www.tynsoe.org/v2/geektool/ but I‘ll recommend you to go find find it by yourself on Google or wait for someone to approve the link with an edit or a comment.